# Computing a variable in modular multiplication

Tags: modular-arithmetic

In the following circumstance, is there a way to compute `b` with certainty, (or assign `b` a value that would yield the same product modulo `k` as the actual `b` would have when multiplied by any other value smaller than `k`)?

```
a * b = c mod k

a, b < k

a, c and k are known

(c is a number that already has the modulus applied; in other words a*b could have yielded
 a product either greater or smaller than k, and by how much we don't know.)
```

Comment: You are asking about modular division here, or more generally modular inverses. Read here about the extended euclidean algorithm to find modular inverses: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Computing_multiplicative_inverses_in_modular_structures

Comment: @Noam thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 0):

$ab\equiv c\pmod{k}\implies$

$ab-c\equiv0\pmod{k}\implies$

$\exists{n\in\mathbb{N}}:ab-c=nk\implies$

$\exists{n\in\mathbb{N}}:b=(nk+c)/a$

---

You know $a$, $c$ and $k$, so search for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $(nk-c)/a\in\mathbb{N}$, and assign this value to $b$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would any `n` that satisfies the condition yield the same product modulo `k` as the actual `b` would have when multiplied by any other value smaller than `k`?

Comment: You say that $b$ is multiplied by $a$. Why should this work for every other value???

Comment: Oh, what I mean is if I multiplied n by any d mod k would that equal b*d mod k?

Comment: Sorry, but i don't understand the question, nor its relation to my answer. Why would you go around multiplying $n$? It's $n$ that you need to find, then you can conclude the value of $b$.

Comment: BTW, please note that I had a sign mistake in the last line (with "$-c$" instead of "$+c$").

Comment: Oops, meant the expression not n itself, sorry.

Comment: You have $a$, $c$ and $k$ at hand. What expression exactly are you referring to?

Comment: Lol, thank you for your patience! I'm asking about the discovered `b`, the expression `(nk + c) / a` Is there only one answer for the discovered `b` mod k?

Comment: You can try a couple of numeric examples and find out. I'm pretty sure that there isn't necessarily a single answer. Perhaps there is a single answer if $k$ is prime (or even coprime to $a$), but I'm really sure about this to be honest.

Comment: @גלעדברקן: Somebody has down-voted this answer, so it is possibly wrong (they didn't leave any comment, so I cannot tell for sure).

Comment: Oh then I'll remove the check mark to hopefully generate more interest. (idk, your logic made sense to me.)